# How to eliminate number input arrows?

Tags: html, input

I was wondering... is there a way to remove those arrows set by default to increase/decrease quantity in number inputs like in the image below?

[Arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDlPA.png)

Answer (score 0):

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

But you still can use your mouse wheel to increase or decrease the number

Comment: Will that remove it from all browsers?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox, Chrome, Edge and IE11

Comment: It doesnt for me (Chrome). :(

Comment: Modified my answer. Works for me with Chrome 70.0.3538.102